# Automating the adding of a website profile via google APIs

Tags: web, google-analytics, addition

I was poking around Google's analytics API docs to see if there is a method that allows the adding of website profiles. Either by using a email/password or session or one time token. Has anyone seen anything?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is a way to programmatically add a profile.  They do have a [good API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html) for reading the data in an existing profile.